# Python VLOOKUP based on dates - Pandas

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe, membership

Having an issue with pandas df, trying to get the "Count" column based on the date, the code should search for the "date range' within the dates column, and if it is present the 'Count' should be copied into the "Posts" column for the corresponding date 
eg: date_range value = 16/02/2017 - code searches for 16/02/2017 in "Dates" column and makes "Posts" equal to the "Count" value of that Date - if the date_range value does not appear - Posts should = 0.

Data Example:

```
Dates     Count date_range  Posts
0   07/02/2017  1   16/12/2016  (should = 5)   
1   01/03/2017  1   17/12/2016  
2   15/02/2017  1   18/12/2016  
3   23/01/2017  1   19/12/2016  
4   28/02/2017  1   20/12/2016  
5   09/02/2017  2   21/12/2016  
6   20/03/2017  2   22/12/2016  
7   16/12/2016  5
```

My code looks like this:

```
    DateList = df['Dates'].tolist()

    for date in df['date_range']:
        if str(date) in DateList:
            df['Posts'] = df['Count']
        else:
            dates_df['Posts'] = 0
```

However this makes the data map the wrong values to "Posts"

Hopefully I explained this correctly! Thanks in advance for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can first create `dict` for matching values and then [`map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.map.html) by `date_range` column:

```
print (df)
        Dates  Count  date_range
0  07/02/2017      1  16/12/2016
1  01/03/2017      1  17/12/2016
2  15/02/2017      1  18/12/2016
3  23/01/2017      1  19/12/2016
4  28/02/2017      1  07/02/2017 <-change value for match
5  09/02/2017      2  21/12/2016
6  20/03/2017      2  22/12/2016
7  16/12/2016      5  22/12/2016

d = df[df['Dates'].isin(df.date_range)].set_index('Dates')['Count'].to_dict()
print (d)
{'16/12/2016': 5, '07/02/2017': 1}

df['Posts'] = df['date_range'].map(d).fillna(0).astype(int)
print (df)
        Dates  Count  date_range  Posts
0  07/02/2017      1  16/12/2016      5
1  01/03/2017      1  17/12/2016      0
2  15/02/2017      1  18/12/2016      0
3  23/01/2017      1  19/12/2016      0
4  28/02/2017      1  07/02/2017      1
5  09/02/2017      2  21/12/2016      0
6  20/03/2017      2  22/12/2016      0
7  16/12/2016      5  22/12/2016      0
```

Comment: Thanks for this, when running this however the dictionary d seems to be empty, despite there being obvious matches across the 2 columns

Comment: Empty? It means there are no match?

Comment: Exactly, but not sure why it cannot see the matches as there are some that I can see when printing df

Comment: What is `print (df.info())` ?

Comment: <class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Int64Index: 108 entries, 0 to 107
Data columns (total 4 columns):
Dates         83 non-null object
Count         83 non-null float64
date_range    108 non-null object
Posts         108 non-null int32
dtypes: float64(1), int32(1), object(2)
memory usage: 3.8+ KB
None

Comment: Hmmm, if convert columns to datetime, how does it work?